# React Router - How to do IndexRedirect, Redirect with dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Previously, I put all routing in one file, like this

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router onUpdate={scrollToTop} history={history} >
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRedirect to="app/dashboard" />   // IndexRedirect

                <Route path="404" component={PageErr404} />
                <Route path="app" component={MainApp}>
                    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                </Route>
                <Redirect from="*" to="404" />        // Redirect
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app-container')
)
```

But now, I use [dynamic routing](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md), and have splitted the code

```
const rootRoute = {
    childRoutes: [{
        path: '/',
        component: require('./containers/App'),
        childRoutes: [
            require('./routes/app'),
            require('./routes/404'),
        ]
    }]
}

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router
            onUpdate={scrollToTop}
            history={history}
            routes={rootRoute}
        />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app-container')
)
```

My question is, how can I IndexRedirect `/` to `/app/dashboard` now?

Also, redirect all other pages `*` to `/404` like before?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **onEnter** event.
should be something like this:

```
const rootRoute = {
    path: '/',
    component: require('./containers/App'),
    indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/app/dashboard') },
    childRoutes: [
        require('./routes/app'),
        require('./routes/404'),
    ]
}
```